Understanding the homogeneous Sobolev space and Poisson equation.
I'm studying Grafakos's book (classical and modern). I have some doubts.
Let $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $1<p<\infty$.
The homogeneous sobolev space is $\dot{H}^{s,p}=\dot{H}^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u\in  S'/P\colon \left\|u+P\right\|_{\dot{L}^p}=\left\|u\right\|_{\dot{L}^p}=\left\|u\right\|_{L^p}\right\}$
Let \begin{equation}
(-\Delta)^{s/2}u=f,\quad (1)
\end{equation}
where $(-\Delta)^{s/2}u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|^2\widehat{u}(\xi))$ is the fractional laplacian.
Question: If $f\in \dot{L}^p$, the problem (1) has a unique solution $u_f$ in the space $\dot{H}^{s,p}$?
